# How do I insert images into a CSSGrid?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to insert these 8 images into a CSSGrid. I made it so that the grid has 4 columns and 2 rows. I set the heigh and width of the img to 100% thinking itd take up the space of one column in each row. Instead the images come out way bigger than intended. Im using a nested grid, which I think im not implementing correctly. For example, Ill set the width and height of the images to 300px and one row will have more than 4 pictures. I think thats cause the images arent taking up the full size of the column but im not sure. When i inspect element I cant seem to see the CSSGrid Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout Master</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="zone green">
            <span>About</span>
            <span>Products</span>
            <span>Our Team</span>
            <span id="Contact">Contact</span>
      </div>
      <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
      <div class="zone blue">
        <img src="data_storage_2_2.png" alt="data storage">
        <img src="desktop_analytics_2.png" alt="desktop analytics">
        <img src="files_2.png" alt="files">
        <img src="monitor_coding_2.png" alt="monitor coding">
        <img src="monitor_settings_2.png" alt="monitor settings">
        <img src= "server_2_2.png" alt="server">
        <img src="server_3.png" alt="server">
        <img src="server_safe_2.png" alt=server safe>
      </div>
      <div class="zone yellow">Made By Cristobal Manrique</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 8fr 1fr;
}

.green {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.green span{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#Contact {
  margin-left: auto; 
}

.zone blue{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;

}
.zone {
    padding:30px 50px; 
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/***********************************************************************
 *  Green Background
 **********************************************************************/
.green{

    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Red Background
 **********************************************************************/
.red{

    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Yellow Background
 **********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Blue Background
 **********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}

img{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo error `.zone blue` to `.zone.blue`

```
.zone.blue{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, im still getting the hang of the selectors as well, so that went right by me.

Comment: I have a problem now though, that now the images are so big they don't fit in the container. How can I fix this? I set height to 300px and left width the same. This way it all fits into each column and row correctly, but the height isnt responsive since im using pixels. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Insted of image tag use DIV tag and add background property

background-image: url('../images/abc.jpg');

Image tag is difficult to align as required. div is best solution.

If you want grid system in more detail , **use flex, it is more efficient and popular one.**
 Refm: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/